# How to update Chromedriver in Windows 7 for using selenium in VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After I updated my chrome I got the "SessionNotCreatedError" error due to outdated Chromedriver. (My Current Chrome version is 95 and my Chromedriver is 92.xx)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Driver As New WebDriver

Driver.Start "Chrome", "www.google.com" '(Line which drops an error)

end sub
```

I have searched for how to update chromedriver on Windows 7 and tested these methods but non of them worked:

1-I have downloaded the appropriate Chromiumdriver version which matches with my current Chrome version (which is 95) and copied it in "C:" path.

2-I have installed Chromedriver by "npm install -g chromedriver" command in CMD

3-I have added new "chromedriver.exe" path to the windows system PATH variable.

Comment: You'll find the answer in this [WiseOwl](https://youtu.be/FoxWcvZzYVk) video. That a look ta the other videos, they are great!

Comment: @ElioFernandes I already used Selenium to open chrome and going to a URL but this problem occurred after I updated my Chrome browser this problem.

Comment: IF  your current Chrome version is 95 and your ``chromedriver.exe`` is 92.xx then you have to download the new version of chromedriver and replace the old one .

Comment: @ElioFernandes I have searched for "chromedriver.exe" in windows explorer search field but all of the found results were in non-system locations and Program Files. All of the found files were in windows download locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video that I told you in the comment above explains everything you need to update your **chromedriver.exe**. When your Chrome version gets update again, you' ll have to get the new chromedriver.exe to match Chrome.

[image]